# How to check whether a go channel is actually waiting for data?

Tags: go, channel, blocking

I want to only proceed with my execution when a certain channel blocks waiting for data to come (the blocking channel is part of a working go routine, supposed to run in parallel).

Like:

```
func foo(c chan bool) {

    go start_blocking(c)
    
    // only come here, when channel c actually blocks!
}

func start_blocking(c chan bool) {

    <-c
}
```

How to achieve this?

Purpose:

The channel is waiting for data to come at some time later and it should be ready in the background, **before** the main execution continues.

Comment: You may use a `select` to execute a communication op OR do something else if that would currently block. Isn't that enough?

Comment: But I just want to test whether the channel blocks, I don't want to consume anything out of it. The try-receive select-pattern also receives/consumes if it can, right?

Comment: One problem with your question: a channel doesn't block; it's communications (send or receive) on it that block.

Comment: @jub0bs but you got the idea? Then maybe rephrase it to: Check when the go routine is actually waiting for a channel to rcv data. Better?

Comment: Waiting for some (number of) task to be completed is normally achieved by using a waitgroup. Are you actually concerned with checking if the channel blocks, or are you mainly interested in seeing if the "initialization before receiving" has been completed?

Comment: @super it's rather the latter. I just want to continue if I am sure that the channel is ready to receive data.

Comment: @marcwellman You do not have such guarantee. Another goroutine may have sent to the channel in the meantime.

Comment: what about "How to check whether an operation on a channel will block?" as title?

Answer (score 5):

You can't "peek" a channel without actually receiving from it. So channels are not a good tool if you really need this functionality. If you have a buffered channel, you can of course check if there's a value in its buffer by checking its length (`len(ch)`), but there's no guarantee the value can still be received if you attempt to do it afterwards.

If you do need this functionality, use a counter instead with atomic reads and writes. It is possible to read a counter's value without decrementing it.

And if you do need a channel, using a `select` with `default` case should suffice: you may do non-blocking send and receive, and if a send or receive would block, the `default` case will be executed without blocking.

Answer (score 3):

Channels don't block; it's [*communications*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types) (*send* or *receive*) on them that may block.

Checking whether a channel communication would block without actually attempting the communication in question is not very idiomatic in Go, for reasons discussed below. However, if that's really what you want, you could do the following. For a given (buffered!) channel `ch`, you could

- check `len(ch) == cap(ch)` to determine whether a send would block;
- check `len(ch) == 0` to determine whether a receive would block.

However, both checks are likely to become stale very quickly, because another goroutine may have sent to or received from the channel shortly after your check; a classic instance of [time-of-check to time-of-use (TOCTOU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use).

And as pointed out in the comments, one caveat of this approach is that it doesn't work for unbuffered channels, for which the two conditions invariably evaluate to `true`.

Comment: that only works with buffered channels, no?

Comment: @MrFuppes Yes, checking `len(ch) == cap(ch)` doesn't work for unbuffered channels, because len and cap are always 0 for unbuffered channels, no matter if a receive or send would block or not.

Comment: That's true: that wouldn't work for unbuffered channels.

Comment: "For a given (unbuffered!) channel" should be "For a given (*buffered*!) channel"